# How can I control foreign connections to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security

We are using different Microsoft SQL Servers (SQL Server 2008 R2) within a Windows LAN network physically seperated each of them. Is there a good strategy how to control incoming connections to the central server?

I mean, how can I prevent/protocol significant changes like `ALTER` to a table structures from "other" users?

Thank you,
Move

Comment: Erm...you want to restrict schema changes to database by certain users? And by users we are referring to applications, right?

Comment: Don't grant people permissions for things they shouldn't be able to do?

Comment: @Danish>Yes, there is the application level and the designer's level.

Comment: So far, db changes are tracked via : 
SELECT  
    CT.ProductID, CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION,  
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT  
FROM  
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES SalesLT.Product, @last_synchronization_version)  
Is there an other way to log structrual changes e.g. get notified ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create different users for different purposes**

Most SQL Server databases have a number of users viewing and accessing data, which makes security a major concern for the administrator. The smart administrator will take full advantage of SQL Server security roles, which grant and deny permissions to groups of users, greatly reducing the security workload.

The first step in protecting your client’s data is determining which users need to view which data and then allowing access to only those users. For example, a payroll clerk probably views salary figures for everyone in your company while team managers have access to salaries for team members. Individual employees have no need to view salaries at all.

The benefits of using roles
Roles are a part of the tiered security model:

```
Login security—Connecting to the server
Database security—Getting access to the database
Database objects—Getting access to individual database objects and data
```

For better understanding read below link guide line you will get answer

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-roles-in-sql-server-security/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/server-and-database-roles-in-sql-server
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you, for your answer and sorry, for being unprecise. The application itself has a fine and secured protection. It can be broken into pieces like 'User A is allowed for financial stuff' and 'User Bee is only allowed for orders'. The app is the only interface to the end user.